Type error on key property of object in a map, Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'
I have been having endless trouble with a typescript error in one location in my code that is preventing me from having successful builds. I even asked on stack overflow and didn't get any answers.
Here is the full repo: https://github.com/markdrecoll/word_game/blob/main/src/hooks/useWordGame.tsx
This is a wordle clone that I followed a guide on but it was written in javascript not typescript.
I managed to get the errors down to just three locations (line 69 and below) at the prevUsedKeys[l.key].
If I set usedKeys initially to [] the error is only in the [] of prevUsedKeys : Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'
If I set usedKeys initially to {} the error is on the whole prevUsedKeys[] and is: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'
If anyone could help with this I would be extremely grateful.
    import { useState } from 'react';
import WORD_LIST from "../constants/word_list.json"

interface LetterInfo {
    key: string,
    color: string,
}

const useWordGame = (secretWord: string | null[]) => {
    const [turn, setTurn] = useState(0);
    const [currentGuess, setCurrentGuess] = useState("");
    const [guesses, setGuesses] = useState([...Array(6)]); // each guess is an array
    const [history, setHistory] = useState([""]); // each guess is a string
    const [isCorrect, setIsCorrect] = useState(false);
    const [usedKeys, setUsedKeys] = useState({});
    const [notificationText, setNotificationText] = useState("");
    const [showNotification, setShowNotification] = useState(false);

    // format a guess into an array of letter objects 
    // e.g. [{key: 'a', color: 'yellow'}]
    const formatGuess = () => {
        let secretWordArray = [...secretWord];
        let formattedGuess = [...currentGuess].map((l) => {
            return { key: l, color: 'grey' };
        });

        // find any green letters
        formattedGuess.forEach((l, i) => {
            if (secretWord[i] === l.key) {
                formattedGuess[i].color = 'green';
                secretWordArray[i] = null;
            }
        });

        // find any yellow letters
        formattedGuess.forEach((l, i) => {
            if (secretWordArray.includes(l.key) && l.color !== 'green') {
                formattedGuess[i].color = 'yellow';
                secretWordArray[secretWordArray.indexOf(l.key)] = null;
            }
        });

        return formattedGuess;
    }

    // add a new guess to the guesses state
    // update the isCorrect state if the guess is correct
    // add one to the turn state
    const addNewGuess = (formattedGuess: Array<LetterInfo>) => {
        if (currentGuess === secretWord) {
            setIsCorrect(true);
        }
        setGuesses(prevGuesses => {
            let newGuesses = [...prevGuesses];
            newGuesses[turn] = formattedGuess;
            return newGuesses;
        })
        setHistory(prevHistory => {
            return [...prevHistory, currentGuess];
        })
        setTurn(prevTurn => {
            return prevTurn + 1;
        })
        setUsedKeys(prevUsedKeys => { 
            formattedGuess.map(l => {
                const currentColor: any = prevUsedKeys[l.key as keyof typeof prevUsedKeys];

                if (l.color === 'green') {
                    prevUsedKeys[l.key] = 'green';
                    return;
                }
                if (l.color === 'yellow' && currentColor !== 'green') {
                    prevUsedKeys[l.key] = 'yellow';
                    return;
                }
                if (l.color === 'grey' && currentColor !== ('green' || 'yellow')) {
                    prevUsedKeys[l.key] = 'grey';
                    return;
                }
            })

            return prevUsedKeys;
        })
        setCurrentGuess("");

    }

    // handle keyup event & track current guess
    // if user presses enter, add the new guess
    const handleKeyup = ({ key }: KeyboardEvent) => {
        let matchFound: Boolean = false;
        if (key === 'Enter') {

            // guess must be a word
            for (let i = 0; i < WORD_LIST.length; i++) {
                if (WORD_LIST[i].toUpperCase() === currentGuess) {
                    matchFound = true;
                }
            }
            if (matchFound !== true){
                setNotificationText("That is not a word.");
                setShowNotification(true);
                return;
            }

            // only add guess if turn is less than 5
            if (turn > 5) {
                return;
            }

            // do not allow duplicate words
            if (history.includes(currentGuess)) {
                setNotificationText("You already tried that word.");
                setShowNotification(true);
                return;
            }

            // check if word is 5 characters
            // if (currentGuess.length !== 5) {
            //     setNotificationText("Word must be 5 letters long.");
            //     setShowNotification(true);
            //     return;
            // }

            console.log("showNotification state in hook", showNotification);
            const formatted: Array<LetterInfo> = formatGuess();
            addNewGuess(formatted);
        }
        if (key === 'Backspace') {
            setCurrentGuess(prev => prev.slice(0, -1));
            return;
        }
        if (/^[A-Za-z]$/.test(key)) {
            if (currentGuess.length < 5) {
                setCurrentGuess(prev => prev + key.toUpperCase());
            }
        }
    }

    // Reset the game board if the user wants to play another game.
    const handleNewGame = () => {
        setTurn(0);
        setCurrentGuess("");
        setGuesses([...Array(6)]) // each guess is an array
        setHistory([]) // each guess is a string
        setIsCorrect(false);
        setUsedKeys({});
        setNotificationText("");
    }

    return {
        turn,
        currentGuess,
        guesses,
        isCorrect,
        usedKeys,
        handleKeyup,
        handleNewGame,
        notificationText,
        showNotification
    }
}

export default useWordGame;


Try useState<TYPE | INTERFACE>(). For example, if I know i have an array of numbers.... useState<number[]>([]).PrevUsedKeys would be, from the look of it, useState<Record<string, string>>({})

That solved it, thank you! I have been looking everywhere for this.
If you write it up as an answer I will mark it as solved. Thanks again!

The underlying issue is that Typescript, although good at inference, is hardly perfect and can't determine a statement such as {} or [] (from its point of view, it would either be considered a Record or Array of either any/unknown depending on the typescript version you're running). A way around this is to provide the type you're trying to match. This can be done by doing: useState<TYPE | INTERFACE>().
Based on the code you provided, it looks like usedKeys is an object that accepts a string as both the key as well as the value. We could then do something like:
const [usedKeys, setUsedKeys] = useState<Record<string, string>>({});

this lets the typescript compiler (tsc) know exactly what to expect.

Very informative and helpful thank you. Also in case this helps anyone in the future part of the issue was I was trying to type prevUsedKeys. Instead of setting the type on usedKeys. Since I was running setUsedKeys(prevUsedKeys) I had to be typing that instead.
